# Using data from model in Chart.js MVC c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model, chart.js

I am trying to make a Chart with Chart.js but i cant get the data from my model into the chart... can someone help me with this?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script >
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
@{ 
    List<String> listKeys = new List<string>();
    List<int> listValues = new List<int>();
    foreach(var x in Model.PageViews)
    {
        listKeys.Add(x.Key + "");
        listValues.Add(x.Value);
    }
}

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: @listKeys,
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: @listValues
        }]
    },
    options: {}
});
```

I've tried multiple things but nothing seems to work...

Comment: Your model should contain properties `IEnumerable<string> Labels` and `IEnumerable<int> Values` and then you use `var labels = @Html.Raw.Json.Encode(Model.Labels))` ect to convert the model to a javascript array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code inside block `@{ }` is server side.
Other content of the `script`-tag is client side.

C# runs `ToString()` method when you use `@listKeys`/`@listValues`. It generates string like `System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]` instead of content of the lists. You need to generate json objects instead.

Use `@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(listKeys))` instead of `@listKeys` to get correct json-object with data.

P.S. It's not good practice to use a lot of server-logic inside views. You can remove your `@{}` block and get json for `Model.PageViews.Keys` and `Model.PageViews.Values`

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to use .NET variables in JavaScript code.
The right way is to create hidden html elements for values who you want to use in js function or use API that returns chart data as Json object.